# How Can I open it?

Tags: samsung

I have a phone it is samsung sm-a8000...
Can someone please tell me how to turn it on.
it only shows logo upside down and stucked.
This is what I did before this error:
I used Root Explorer then I change something in the system folder then I rebooted it and it doesnt open up in home anymore..please help me

Comment: With these details all we can recommend you is to "do something else" to revert your changes. You could e.g. restore the backup you've certainly made before modifying system stuff. If you didn't make a backup (really???), all that's left is to flash the device with a fresh ROM.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard reset your Android device it will normally revert changes you've made. Here's how you can do this

[Here the link to it](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-104024/)